# Redirect on Custom page after one time login link

Tags: 7, users

I created password reset link using `user_pass_reset_url` function. This is redirecting to `user/uid/edit` page after click login.

How to redirect on custom url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done using Custom code `drupal_goto`. I checked the current path and redirect it using `drupal_goto`. So whenever the user go to user/edit link he will be redirected.

Answer (score 2):

Since the form builder for user/reset/%/%/% ([user_pass_reset()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_pass_reset/7)) is using the following code to redirect the user, you can only replace the form builder with one that redirects the users where you want.

```
      $token = drupal_hash_base64(drupal_random_bytes(55));
      $_SESSION['pass_reset_' . $user->uid] = $token;
      drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/edit', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
```

If you do that (which means implementing `hook_menu_alter()`), be careful of how the workflow is modified. If you need to change that radically, and you want to be sure not to introduce security risks, I would rather:

- Alter the URL returned from `user_pass_reset_url()`, so that users are redirected to your page
- Implement a form builder for your page using the code used by `user_pass_reset()` as guideline

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_drupal_goto_alter` to customize the current user password reset URL, e.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drupal_goto_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  if (module_exists('token') && arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == 'reset') {
    $path = user_pass_reset_url();
  }
}
```

Where `user_pass_reset_url()` is your custom function providing new URL.